# Using angular using $interval or a promise to run code when api is completed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, promise

I have an api call to that is a bit slow.

```
$http.jsonp(url, {
    params: {
      'client': 'translate_about',
      'alpha': 1,
      'hl': 'en'
    }
  })
    .success(function (data) {
      home.translate.list = data.sl;
      //console.log(data.sl);
    });
```

*this next block can happen before or in parallel with `home.translate.list` is ready*.  Therefore, when `home.translate.list` is successful I need to another block of code to update.

```
  home.modalOn = function (val) {
    //open modal
    home.isModal = true;
    //this if block must wait for home.translate.list to be ready.
    if(typeof home.translate.list !== 'undefined'){
      home.activePageSelection = home.translate.list[val];
      //call wikipedia and get data
      home.callWiki(home.translate.list[val]);
    }
  };
  $scope.$watch(function () {
    return location.hash
  }, function (value) {
    var currentRouteParam = value.split('/').slice(-1)[0];

    if (currentRouteParam !== '') {
      home.modalOn(currentRouteParam);
    } else {
      home.modalOff()
    }

  });
```

### **Question:**

How can I make sure `home.translate.list` is defined before executing the if block?  Caveat, without putting it in the `$http.success` block.

Comment: where did you call  `home.modalOn` ?

Comment: When the hash changes.  Which can be problematic when someone deeplinks

Comment: added the reference @AnikIslamAbhi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
if (currentRouteParam !== '') {
    var interval = $interval(function() {
        if (typeof home.translate.list !== 'undefined') {
            $interval.cancel(interval);
            home.modalOn(currentRouteParam);
        }
    }, 500);

}
```

**N:B**:

you have to inject **[$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval)** service in your controller

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to put the `watch` in a function and call it in the `success` block

```
.success(function (data) {
    home.translate.list = data.sl;
    watchHash();  
    //console.log(data.sl);
});

function watchHash() {
    $scope.$watch(function () {
    ...
}
```

Comment: that way you will be sure it'll always wark :)

Answer (score 0):

You could save the promise for the translation instead of the list in your vm:

```
home.translatePromise = $http.jsonp(url, {
    params: {
      'client': 'translate_about',
      'alpha': 1,
      'hl': 'en'
    }
  })
  .then(function (response) {
      return response.data.sl;
  });
```

Then reference the promise instead of the raw value:

```
home.modalOn = function (val) {
  //open modal
  home.isModal = true;
  //this if block must wait for home.translate.list to be ready.
  home.translatePromise.then(function(list){
    home.activePageSelection = list[val];
    //call wikipedia and get data
    home.callWiki(list[val]);
  });
};
```

Comment: op mentioned **Caveat, without putting it in the $http.success block.**

Comment: I took that caveat to mean only executing the activePageSelction/callWiki code in the home.modalOn path.

Comment: @BradBarber oddly the list is coming up undefined. any ideas?

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on `return response.data.sl;` and inspect the response object to make sure it's what you expect?

Comment: `.success` is deprecated, so you should be using `.then` now which doesn't spread the response object. So, with `.then` it needs to return response.data.sl.